# A black screen gets displayed on top of Kendo Chart in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, charts, kendo-ui

Sometimes we experience a black/distorted screen covering some area of the internet explorer where we are using Kendo Chart to display the graph :+
[Check Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQVN3.png)

I want to confirm whether its a Kendo chart issue or an Internet Explorer issue or both combined. Any leads on this would be great.

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).From the [Kendo UI Chart document](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/index), it seems that the demos works well in IE 11 on my machine, you could check them. If they are working well on your side, might be the issue is related to your code, please share it. If try are still not working, perhaps the issue is related to the IE browser setting, try to reset the browser setting.

Comment: this is a very sporadic issue, like it comes once in 10 times, so I had to raise ticket with microsoft team, so i wanted to sure its an IE issue...

Comment: Without related code, it is hard to make sure whether the issue is related to IE browser or not. So, it is better to share the related code. Besides, from your description, this issue is sporadic. perhaps the issue is related to the cache, please try to clear the cache and the browser data.